# Output text in dialogflow cx chatbot containing URLs is repeating URLS excessively

Tags: dialogflow-cx

When my Dialogflow CX chatbot is live on a website, some output text containing URLs is being repeated excessively. For instance, if the original text is "Here is some output text. Visit my website at www.website.com," it appears on the website within the chatbot as "Here is some output text. Visit my website at www.website.comwww.website.comwww.website.com...," and the URL keeps repeating as you scroll down the conversation. This repetition seems to only occur if two URLS are present within one output.

I've tried splitting the text into two dialog sections, and it still occurs. I've also tried flowing to a new page to split the text and it occurs then too. I suppose I could limit the URLS to one per output but that is not feasible with my current bot due to the nature of it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share how you have defined the fulfilment response, otherwise it is not possible to help.